# How can I obtain a one-week Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, denmark

I'm a grad student in US on F-1 visa. This summer I'm planning to visit Denmark for one week to attend a conference and then come back to US. I've the admission letter to attend from the university.

Does anyone know what I need to do (what application(s) I need to fill out and what documents I need to submit)?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE.  Your question seems to be a duplicate of multiple questions here.  Denmark being part of Schengen aquis the standard Schengen rules apply.  http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/861/denmark-and-schengen-border-controls?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does applying for a multiple entry Schengen visa instead of a single entry the first time hurt my chances of a visa getting granted?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5538/does-applying-for-a-multiple-entry-schengen-visa-instead-of-a-single-entry-the-f)  There are great many other questions regarding the Schengen visa as well.

Comment: @Karlson one of those is about multiple entries and the other is about schengen border controls; he's asking about the documents required?  Although, I'd be surprised if we don't have it somewhere on this site already...

Comment: Thank you, Mark Mayo! I'm not duplicating any previous questions!

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=schengen+visa

Comment: I was looking all over Travel.SE.. I could not find a plain simple Schengen visa request question.. So I guess this is the first!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to visit the Danish embassy/consulate (or perhaps an embassy of another Schengen country which handles applications for Denmark in your current location), and fill the [application](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nyidanmark.dk%2FNR%2Frdonlyres%2FD4785E07-7C27-4AC6-970D-7FF3A8C7602D%2F0%2Fapplication_schengen_visa.pdf&ei=BTIqUcuAFOiL0AWXxYGwDw&usg=AFQjCNF2l_iM97AvjN8cD_-U6Gu-6fdjnw&sig2=hDo4yBeGxb6lpc_aqMXUTQ&bvm=bv.42768644,d.d2k) provided there. Usually you will be asked for the following documents:

- A copy of your passport a long with your original passport.
- Passport size photo, clear, no head cover, no smile, light background.
- Bank statement for the last six months to show that you can cover the trip expenses.
- Or, a job certificate from your employer showing your income.
- Invitation letters from sponsors (if available)
- Application fee (differs from embassy to another, country to another)

These were the usual requests, sometimes they ask for more or less. It also depends on the country you request the visa from, but generally getting the Schengen visa is easy as long as you provided the papers they ask for. Remember, it takes around 2 weeks usually for the visa to be issued.