# What is the least useful passport in the world, visa-wise?

Tags: visas, passports, factoids

An Israeli colleague and I were debating the merits of his passport, and that he can't travel to many countries.

So with the proviso that a passport is not 'useful' if you require a visa to get into another country, which is the LEAST useful passport (ie the one that requires visas for the most countries)?

Comment: How about North Korea, Afganistan, Somalia, Sudan, Mauritania

Comment: http://www.visahq.com/citizens/ has all the info but no sorting.

Comment: You can acquire a passport from the Republic of Texas ([yes, that is a real thing...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Texas_(group))) which is not actually recognized by any nation of the world other than the Republic of Texas themselves. Not sure if that counts since it is technically not a real country, but it's definitely my best bet for "least useful passport".

Comment: @hippietrail other factoid questions are "useful" in the sense that someone may use the information in the answer to do something, for example go to [this unusual place](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/19941/324). I don't see someone choosing to acquire a un-useful passport. I haven't close-voted this question yet, though.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: You've only listed one property of one type of factoid question. Not all factoid questions have that property. I think the one thing they have in common is "many travellers are curious about this". We've never debated whether we should have such questions but the defacto consensus so far has been to accept them.

Comment: Relevant fun fact: The most useful one is the Finnish passport.

Comment: The [passportindex.org](https://www.passportindex.org/comparebyPassport.php) site provides a list of the passports sorted by visa-power. According to them Afghanistan provides least visa-free travel.

Answer (score 16):

After several bits of research over lunch and some arguments, we found the [following article in the International Business Times](http://www.ibtimes.com/best-passports-have-unrestricted-travel-around-world-1422038):

The key paragraph would be:

> On the flipside, passport holders of Kosovo (38), Lebanon (38), Sri
>   Lanka (38), Sudan (38), Nepal (37), Eritrea (36), Palestinian
>   Territory (36), Pakistan (32), Somalia (32) and Iraq (31) have the
>   least visa-free travel options among all countries and territories
>   surveyed, save those whose passports were issued in Kabul,
>   Afghanistan. Afghani passport holders can only visit 13 percent of the
>   world, or just 28 countries, free of formalities.

indicating that visa-wise, it's **Afghanistan** who has the worst passport.

Note: The article was written after South Sudan formed, so might or might not be up to date, if more visa agreements have been formed with other countries, as Johnathan suggested in his answer.

Comment: I am surprised that the [DRC did not make it to the list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Congolese_citizens). Transit is often restricted, getting visas is usually not easy either, the passport is horribly expensive and valid only 2 years. It's certainly not very attractive.

Comment: Do we trust the *International Business Times* on this, given that their knowledge of international business doesn't extend to the fact that the Afghani is the currency of Afghanistan? The people are Afghans.

Comment: Now available as an infographic: http://magazine.good.is/infographics/how-powerful-is-your-passport .

Comment: @pnuts still not sold on the answers :/

Comment: As an Afghan I can agree no more. We have the worst passport.

Answer (score 13):

A passport is a document attesting to both the holder's identity and nationality. Since the requirements for identification (name, photograph, birthdate, signature, etc.) have been internationally standardized for some time, I would say the usefulness of the passport will be governed by the usefulness of holding a particular nationality. Your passport will only be accepted by as valid by countries which recognize your government. Therefore, the fewer countries your state is recognized by, the less useful your passport is.

The answer cannot therefore be Taiwan or Israel, as a holder of one of their passports can still enter many other countries. I would venture to say the least useful passport is that of **[Somaliland](http://www.somaliland.us/)**. Somaliland is a de facto independent country; while it is nominally part of Somalia, it has functioned as a separate state for two decades. However, no other country recognizes it, and no other country will accept a Somalilan passport. A similar situation exists for several post-Soviet states which are only recognized by certain other post-Soviet states and/or by Russia, and others like Western Sahara and Northern Cyprus.

Among states with wider recognition, I would rank the passports least useful to a traveler are those for which it is most difficult to obtain an exit visa. After all, even if another country will give you or waive an entry visa, it does you no good if you cannot get out. I can think of no more extreme case than the **DPRK (North Korea)**, whose government is recognized by nearly every other UN member, but from which it is almost impossible to leave if not on official state business. The many crossing the border into China are not exactly collecting entry stamps at the airport.

I don't think the other "freedom of movement" rankings are relevant to this specific question, as they are rankings of the number of countries where *visa-free* travel is possible. In relative terms, a passport holder who can never even apply for a visa is in a far worse situation than someone who must apply for one (and in some cases, visas are available upon arrival for a nominal fee, not much more effort than visa-free travel), hence why a North Korean passport is less *useful* than an Iraqi or Afghan passport.

Comment: Isn't their own government the main problem for North Koreans? That's a completely different problem.

Comment: We wondered about North Korea but they do have passports, and the question was about visas, not one's own government.

Comment: @Annoyed along those lines, there's lots of variations on this question I'd love to ask, but they're more appropriate for [Expats.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates?referrer=pHo7j1-e9Kt9c2qQO4fLxA2) (:

Comment: @MarkMayo DPRK probably has internal and external passports like most of the former Soviet Bloc states.

Answer (score 12):

By far it is the Northern Cyprus passport. If you have it you can visit only 6 countries in the World, Turkey (obviously), USA, UK, Australia, France and Pakistan.
However, the Country itself is not recognized as UN member.

Comment: Maybe it should read “if that's all you have”. Many people living in Northern Cyprus should be able to get a proper Cypriot passport now, some of those who immigrated after 1974 might be able to get a Turkish one (even if I am not 100% sure of the latter).

Comment: Yes, you are right. They are able to get at least the turkish or cypriot (greek-side) passport. So, yes, if this is all you have, is more precise :)

Answer (score 6):

The Henley Visa Restrictions Index by the agency of the same name pretty much does that for you, there's even a wikipedia page for that, according to which the lowest ranking countries are
Iran, Nepal, Lebanon, Pakistan, Afghanistan
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_movement#Entrance_restrictions_in_certain_countries