# How safe is souther suburbs of Paris?

Tags: safety, paris

I will be moving to Fontenay aux Roses while my work is in Gif-sur-Yvette. I'll be using RER B daily and will be living alone. As a young female, I am a bit concerned for my safety. I would really appreciate it if you could point out places to avoid and if these areas are safe! Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81146/what-is-the-most-dangerous-area-of-paris-or-its-suburbs-according-to-police-st

Comment: Please see the discussion we had [here on questions about safety](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/1906/32134) and re-phrase your question so that it becomes suitable for our format and gets answered instead of closed as off-topic, opinion-based or unclear. See also our [help center on what and how to ask and not to ask](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I don't know about Fontenay, but Gif and the other cities along the southern end of RER B are very quiet. You meet a lot of retirees and cats.

Comment: And also, if you're working from Gif, it would probably be easier for you to live along the RER B, wouldn't it? In Gif, Bures, Orsay, Palaiseau. All of which are very quiet places.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about living somewhere, not travelling.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on where exactly you live and what are your hours. If you come back home late at night and you live in the middle of what they call a "cité", then it might not be the safest place in the world at that time.

If you come back home during peak hours in RER B and you live in a house in the residential areas, then it should be ok.