# Turkish single-entry visa stamped in transit by mistake. Can I still use it to enter Turkey?

Tags: visas, air-travel, turkey, visa-expiration

I was intending to transit in Istanbul, going to Tbilisi for a week and then another week in Istanbul. I have visas for both countries. While I was in transit in Istanbul, I was directed to a wrong gate and the officer stamped my Turkish visa with an entrance stamp. When I realized that, and told him that I was transiting, he stamped my visa with an exit stamp. My Turkish visa is single entry only and I am now in Tbilisi.

Will I be able to enter Turkey as planned, or am I unable since I have both entrance and exit stamps on my visa?

Comment: I'm going to guess here, but entry and exit stamps on the same day at the same time and place would be good evidence to back up your tale of what happened. Mistakes happen.Maybe hang on to boarding cards and other evidence of your travels on that day.

Comment: @DJClayworth Perhaps, but it seems relatively likely that an airline check-in agent would just look at the visa, see it is single-entry and used, and deny boarding.

Comment: @ZachLipton I guess OP could buy a throwaway ticket to show to the airline, although that could be tricky if luggage is involved

Answer (score 5):

> Will I be able to enter Turkey as planned

No, definitely not *as planned*. You *might* be allowed to enter (I doubt it) but can expect at the very least to have to provide quite a lot of clarification. To be directed to the wrong gate is already very unusual, for you then to accept that misdirection makes the chance of being in a situation that happens quite often (for which there may be special procedures in place) extremely slight. Signs in IST are visible, of a high standard, and bilingual:

[image: IST airport signs]
*Image courtesy Mike at [upgrd](http://upgrd.com/mike/turkish-airlines-business-class-lounge-istanbul.html)*

> or am I unable since I have both entrance and exit stamps on my visa?

Technically, you entered Turkey once the ink from the entry stamp hit your passport. That is your single entry used up, with or without an exit stamp. With an exit stamp on the same day showing the same location and stamp number may however help with any 'negotiation' required with a consulate.

Given the significance for you, I suggest you contact the Turkish Embassy in Tbilisi as soon as possible:

Telephone: 00 995 32 225 20 72 -73-74-75-76

I would appreciate it you would revert here in due course with the (hopefully happy!) outcome.