# Schengen visa granted; apply for a new one to extend visit?

Tags: schengen

My friends and I applied for a Hungary tourist visa for 7 days and opted for multiple entry. We were planning to be in Budapest for 7 days and another 6 days in Amsterdam.

The thing is, when we got our passport back, it stated 7 days' duration of stay and single entry. We wanted to go to Amsterdam for another 6 days, however. Clearly its not possible as we were only granted 7 days.

Would it be okay to apply for another Schengen visa from the date our Hungarian visa expires? We are planning to go to Hungary from 14th-20th of April 2016 (7 days' duration of stay in the visa), and planning to fly to Amsterdam from Budapest on 20th-26th of April.

Comment: You did not tell Hungary about your complete itinerary, so they could not consider it. You should have told them on your visa application that you intended to stay 6 days in Amsterdam.

Comment: Thnks so much for the info @MichaelHampton. Initially we were not thinking of Amsterdam.  We actually got extra leave vacation granted by our company later when we already applied the visa. And it just so happened that they have given the leave from 20th-27th.  So we were thinking we're already somewhere in Europe so might as well use up the extra leave days there.  Is there any possibility we would be allowed to apply for Netherlands?

Comment: Please do not use ALLCAPS; it is commonly interpreted as shouting.

Answer (score 1):

Most Schengen visas allow you to visit *multiple* Schengen states in a *single* trip. This counts as **one** entry. Once you're in, you can cross the internal borders. (You still have to abide by your filed itinerary.)

Look at [this border crossing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19941/one-foot-in-belgium-and-the-other-in-the-netherlands) from another SE question. Schengen makes it possible.

Comment: In this case they were only granted 7 days total duration, but now want to stay 13-14 days so I'm not sure this is an answer to the actual question.

Comment: Their problem is not traveling, their problem is the number of days allowed and you do not help at all in that respect.

Comment: O.m. I think maybe you misread the question...

Comment: @Willeke, the question was edited. I *thought* I had answered the original one.

Comment: Hi guys thnks for the info...but do u think its ok to apply for Netherlands visa then?